# Identifying Great Grandfather who was born about 1870 in Louisiana, USA?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, germany, louisiana

I am trying to find some family information, or any information on my Great Grandfather on my moms side of the family. I have looked on Ancestry.Com and have hit a blank wall.

His name was Acee Kinchen. We have no family records of my Great Grandfather only hearsay and what little I found on ancestry.com:

- He was born 1870 in Tickfaw Louisiana.
- I have no record of death.
- We believe he was of German decent.
- He was married twice with two sons by his 1st marriage and one by his second marriage.

My mom was told that the name Kinchen meant little chicken in German. The only record for the spelling of his first name (Acee) is from a census report on ancestry.com Two other possible spellings for the last name are(Kindchen and or Kinchin).

My Grandfather, was born in Ticfaw Louisiana in 1921 and passed away in New Orleans Louisiana in 1989.

Any history whether good or not so good would be a big help to me and my mother.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  Before we can proceed with trying to focus and answer your question, we need to take our Privacy Policy in the [help/on-topic] into account.  Would you be able to give us the years (or approximate years) and countries that your great grandfather and grandfather were born in, please?

Comment: What sourced information do you have and why do you believe there is a German origin?

Comment: Definitely need context - where and when. "Kindchen" means "little child," so very possible as a surname. All the spellings used by the OP are variants; which is primary may depend on local dialect/ pronounciation. Very rare, very few entries in the historical addressbooks at GenWiki (1850 & 1936 Aachen, 1884 Duisburg). Acee is not a typical given name, may be "A.C.," for which there are a number of matches at Ancestry.com

Comment: @lejonet the only information I have on that is from my mother. Unfortunately we have no records on my GGF.

Comment: @bgwiehle the only information I have on the spelling of his first name is from a census report on ancestry.com and we know/realize that there were a lot of misspelling back in the day on those.

Comment: @PolyGeo first I want to thank everyone that is trying to help and if I post or do something wrong it's not intentional, it's from lack of experience within all of this and I apologize up front. My GGF was born 1870 in Tickfaw Louisiana. I have no record of death but we believe it may be around the 1940's. My GF was also born in Ticfaw Louisiana in 1921 and passed away in New Orleans Louisiana in 1989.

Comment: Does this look like him in the "Florida State Census, 1935," database with images, FamilySearch (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:MNVC-FWK : accessed 6 April 2016), A C Kinchen, , Hillsborough, Florida; citing line 39, State Archives, Tallahassee; FHL microfilm 2,425,159.

Comment: Or could this be his burial: "Find A Grave Index," database, FamilySearch (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:QVKD-CRFC : accessed 6 April 2016), A. C. Kinchen, 1952; Burial, , Tangipahoa Parish, Louisiana, United States of America, Antioch Cemetery; citing record ID 40387415, Find a Grave, http://www.findagrave.com.

Comment: To fit with our focussed Q&A format perhaps you can now formulate a more precise question like "Establishing identity of Acee/A.C. Kinchen in several Louisiana and Florida records?"

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no surname like "Kindchen" in Germany today.

I found only the name "Kennchen" in the Ruhr region:

http://legacy.stoepel.net/de/Default.aspx?name=Kennchen

 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruhr

Comment: Welcome To G&FH SE! Note that Geogen uses modern telephone data, so surnames that have died out (or completely emigrated) are not included.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few Asa and Acey's in Louisiana in the correct age range.

The two census records for Tangipahoa Parish are:

- [Asa Kinchen in the 1940 census](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:VY5L-WNN); and
- [Acey T Rinchan in the 1900 census](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:MSRC-22P).

Comment: Yes :) Here are the familysearch links:1940 census: https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:VY5L-WNN 1900 census: https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:MSRC-22P

Answer (score 0):

I have found census records for Acey Kinchen, born in July 1870 in Louisiana.  He was married to Josephine Kinchen in the 1900 US Federal Census for St. Mary, LA, and worked as a farm laborer. He is listed with 2 sons/stepsons.

The 1880 Census has him listed as Asey Kinchen (people weren't as particular about spelling back then) living as the grandson in St. Mary with none other than his Grandfather by the same name, which I think is sweet. His mother is listed as Christianna Kinchen. If this sounds like your ancestor, let me know and I'll see if I can provide you with the records and find more.